# Using Python3 and the argparse module, can I disallow an argument if a different one was passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, command-line-arguments

For example, say the user passes an argument such as

```
python3 myscript.py -a
```

And I also want them to be able to pass

```
python3 myscript.py -b
```

But I **don't** want them to be able to pass both at the same time such as

```
python3 myscript.py -a -b
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm not too familiar with argparse as of yet and the documentation is kinda tough to comprehend.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [Mutual exclusion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

Comment: @LevLevitsky, that looks like an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) of arguments. Here's a minimal example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a', help='Do A', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-b', help='Do B', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.a:
    print('A!')
if args.b:
    print('B!')
```

Test:

```
$ python myscript.py -h
usage: myscript.py [-h] [-a | -b]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a          Do A
  -b          Do B
$ python myscript.py -a
A!
$ python myscript.py -b
B!
$ python myscript.py -a -b
usage: myscript.py [-h] [-a | -b]
myscript.py: error: argument -b: not allowed with argument -a
```